# How can I parse this JSON Pokemon Dictionary? Pokemon API (swift 3)

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I have an issue with parsing JSON data from new version of the Pokemon API, specifically with values of the "name" in "type" key.

Json looks like this:

```
"types": [
    {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
            "name": "poison",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
        }
    },
    {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
            "name": "grass",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
        }
    }
],
"weight": 69
```

After parsing in Alamofire i'm got the next solution:

```
if let types = dict["types"] as? [Dictionary<String, String>] , types.count > 0 {

                if let type = types[0]["type"] as? Dictionary<String, String> {

                    if let name = type["name"] {
                        self._type = name.capitalized
                    }
                }

                print("TypeAA: \(self._type)")

            } else {

                self._type = ""
            }
```

And this line also not be executed.
print("TypeAA: (self._type)")
Please advise, how can I parse and get the value of "name" in key named is "type" correctly?

Comment: It is much easier to use [Decodable](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375) instead of manually parsing the response.

Comment: Thank @Kamran, but pls advise on these code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `dict["types"] as? [Dictionary<String, String>]` because an item in `types` can't be cast to `Dictionary<String, String>`. `item` has integers like `"slot": 2` and dictionaries `"type": {...}`. So it must be cast to `[String : Any]` first.

```
if let types = dict["types"] as? [Any], types.count > 0 {
    if let firstObject = (types.first as? [String : Any]),
        let type = firstObject["type"] as? [String : String],
        let name = type["name"] {
            self._type = name.capitalized
    }
}
```

if you want name of each item, you have to loop through the `items` array.

Comment: Your solution works but your statement is wrong. `[Dictionary<String, String>]` **is** an array of dictionaries, too. And if you check `first` the check for empty is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Or try something similar like this here:

```
if let types = dict["types"] as? [Any] {
    guard types.count > 0 else {
        return
    }

    for elment in types {
        if let type = elment["type"] as? [String:Any] {
            let name = type["name"] as! String
            // Do what you want with it here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlamofireObjectMapper to parse the JSON response from Alamofire very easily.

```
class PokemonTypesResponse: Mappable {
    var types:[Types]?
    var weight:Int?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        types <- map["types"]
        weight <- map["weight"]
    }
}

class Types: Mappable {
    var slot:Int?
    var name:String?
    var url:String?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        slot <- map["slot"]
        type <- map["type.name"]
        url  <- mapp["type.url"]
    }
}
```

Perform the request with alamofire and use

```
.responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[PokemonTypesResponse]>) in
switch response.result {
            case .success:
                //this is the response as PokemonTypesResponse
                response.result.value 
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
```

to map the JSON result
I haven't tested it, I wrote it based on my experience.
I hope it works and it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the first conditional downcast fails.

The value for key `types` is `[Dictionary<String, Any>]` (note the nested dictionary in the JSON) and not `[Dictionary<String, String>]`.

So basically this works

```
 if let types = dict["types"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] , types.count > 0 {
    if let type = types[0]["type"] as? Dictionary<String, String> {
       if let name = type["name"] {
          self._type = name.capitalized
       }
    }
    print("TypeAA: \(self._type)")
 } else {
    self._type = ""
 }
```

But the *pyramid of doom* is cumbersome and **never** check for an empty array with `.count > 0` so this is more efficient

```
 if let types = dict["types"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>], 
    let firstType = types.first, let typeInfo = firstType["type"] as? Dictionary<String, String>,
    let name = typeInfo["name"] {
       self._type = name.capitalized
       print("TypeAA:", self._type)
 } else {
    self._type = ""
 }
```

If you need to consider all names you have to use a loop

```
 if let types = dict["types"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
    for type in types {
        if let typeInfo = type["type"] as? Dictionary<String, String>,
           let name = typeInfo["name"] {
           print("TypeAA:", name)
        }
   }
 } else {
    self._type = ""
 }
```

If you want to print all names comma separated use

```
if let types = dict["types"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
    let names = types.compactMap { type -> String? in
        guard let typeInfo = type["type"] as? Dictionary<String, String>,
            let name = typeInfo["name"] else { return nil }
        return name
    }
    print(names.joined(separator: ", "))
}
```

Comment: #Vadian, your solution is easy to understand and it works. It is very helpful to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry, i am still confuse.

Comment: sorry, i am still confuse.
i use your loop code, but it seem only one type is being got correctly.
The console log is like below.</br>
    TypeAA: poison
    TypeAA: bug
</br>Did arrive here?
    2018-11-25 18:27:20.067718+0700 PokeMum[11401:1131765] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
    2018-11-25 18:27:20.067883+0700 PokeMum[11401:1131765] TIC Read Status 
    [1:0x0]: 1:57
</br>
And my expected is print out: "Poison/Grass" (2 types), how to perform?

Comment: There is no string `bug` in the given JSON. And `TypeAA: poison / TypeAA: bug`  are 2 types. Each type is printed separately.

Comment: Thnks @vadian, one more question, when using your loop code, how to print out the string like this: "Poison/Grass".
I am a newbie, pls advice.

Comment: i will check your sussget. Thx you so much.